# Angular5 *ngfor not working, but there is no error

Tags: json, angular, angular5, ngfor

I'm facing a problem with Angular at the moment.
I want to read data from my server API and want to display it with *ngfor in a html document.
I can receive the data from the API, but i can't display it.
I took the example code from the tour of heroes tutorial and changed it:
The data gets through to my angular app. I can console.log it and see it in chrome development console.
I tried to display other data that I get from my api and it is working. You can see the data commented out in heroes.components.ts.

Who can help me with this?
If you want to see some more of the code like imports please tell me. But i guess everything needed imported as there are no error messages, i can get the data from my api and i can display some data (sadly not the data i need).

I tried several ideas to solve this from some other posts, but can't get it working.

Here are some Code Snippets:
This is my hero.service.ts

imports...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Hero } from '../model/hero';
import { MessageService } from '../message.service';
import { Response } from '@angular/http/src/static_response';

getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
 console.log("GET HEROES IN HEROES.SERVICE");
 return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
   .pipe(
     tap(Hero => console.log(`fetched heroes: `)),
     catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
   );
```

//I also tried to just use return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl);

This is my
heroes.components.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../../model/hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Response } from '@angular/http/src/static_response';
// For use of map
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})

export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes: Observable<Hero[]>;
  // I tried to display some data 
  // heroes: any[] = [
  //   {
  //     "name": "Douglas  Pace"
  //   }
  // ];
  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.getHeroes();
    // undefined
    console.log("ONINIT");
    console.log(this.heroes);
  }

  getHeroes(): void {
    console.log("GET HEROES IN HEROES.COMPONENT");
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
    .subscribe(  
      function(response: Hero[]) { 
     
        console.log("RESPONSE IN HEROES COMPONENT");
        console.log(this.heroes);
        var res = response["data"];
        // console.log(res.json());
        this.heroes = res;
        console.log(this.heroes);
        console.log(response["data"]);
      
      },
      function(error) { 
        console.log("Error happened" + error)
        
      },
      function() { 
        console.log("the subscription is completed")
        //This shows me the right data.
        console.log(this.heroes[5].id);
        console.log(this.heroes[5].titel);
        console.log(this.heroes[5].name);
        console.log(this.heroes[5].vorname);
      }
    );
  }
```

My html file:

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>

<!-- <input type=text ng-model="hero"> -->
// I gave it a try with and without *ngIf="heroes"
<!-- only show the list IF the data is available -->
<div *ngIf="heroes">
  <h3>Heroes are available and are displayed</h3>
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
      {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</div>

<button (click)="button()">
    Suchen
  </button>

<div *ngIf="heroes">
  <table class="heroes">
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Titel</th>
        <th>Nachname</th>
        <th>Vorname</th> 
      </tr>
      //I tried async as the data is maybe not available from the 
      beginning. Also tried async on hero as heroes is created on init 
      and single heros are added with the function getHeroes();
      <tr *ngFor='let hero of heroes | async'>
        <a routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}">
        <td>{{hero.id}}</td>
        <td>{{hero.titel}}</td>
        <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
        <td>{{hero.vorname}}</td>
        </a> 
        <button class="delete" title="delete hero"
        (click)="delete(hero)">x</button>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <pre>{{heroes | json}}</pre>
```

If got a hero interface. Should be my model. Only Last and First name are needed.

```
export interface Hero {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
  titel?: string;
  vorname: string;
}
```

The JSON I returned from my API. Online Json formatter says it is valid json.

```
 {"status":"Success","data":
[{"id":"36","name":"Hero","vorname":"Super","titel":"Dr.",},
{"id":"34","name":"Man","Spider":"Ines","titel":""}],
"message":"Retrieved all HEROES"}
```

Comment: is this Http or HttpClient?

Comment: It is HttpClient

Comment: I added my imports now. I guess it's more important than I first thought.

Comment: The problem is in your `subscribe`. You set `(response: Hero[])` when `response.data` IS `Hero[]` not `response`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.heroService.getHeroes()
.subscribe(  
  function(response: Hero[]) { }
```

Your problem could be here. Your response is an object with (let's say, interface):

```
interface DataResponse {
     success: string;
     data?: Hero[];
}
```

Because you set `response: Hero[]` and there's no `data` property in your `Hero` interface, `response["data"]` returns null and you'll never get your data. If you run `response.data`, you'll probably get an error saying `data is not defined in Hero` etc...

Change to the following:

```
this.heroService.getHeroes()
     .subscribe((response: DataResponse) => {
         this.heroes = response["data"];
     });
```

Comment: Yes :) This helped me a lot.
I changed the body of my getHeroes() method in hero.services.ts to 
return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl);
After that i could subscribe to (response: Response).
Don't know why I missed out this before.

Comment: Nice. Glad it helped you and please mark it as answer so others can reference this later :)

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems to be ok but i see an error in your json format here

> "titel":"Dr.",},

try to remove the comma after Dr and give it a try

> "titel":"Dr."},

Comment: Thank you. Sadly this is not the problem. I changed my json data for showing you an example. In my data everything is fine and I checked it on Jsonformatter...  So this comma is not there in my real data. It was just a typo. But thanks for your try.